# full-text search condition in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
 select * from quotestable where contains(RelatedKeyword, 'Benjamin Franklin Quotes')
```

returns an error

```
 Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 1
 Syntax error near 'Franklin' in the full-text search condition 'Benjamin Franklin'.
```

I am surprised as to why. It should ideally search for the word but it has returned error message.

Comment: Where What Contains??(RelatedKeyword, 'Benjamin Franklin Quotes')

Comment: why not to use: select * from quotestable where RelatedKeyword like '%Benjamin Franklin Quotes%'

Comment: These are full text indexed so using contains I feel is better than using like for performance reasons. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Venkat you have to enclose the 'Benjamin Franklin Quotes' with double quotes like this '"Benjamin Franklin Quotes"'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are searching for the complete string `Benjamin Franklin Quotes` in `RelatedKeyword` column

You need to use double quotes to escape the space between your words.

```
select * 
from quotestable 
where contains(RelatedKeyword, '"Benjamin Franklin Quotes"')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using like this

```
select * from quotestable where RelatedKeyword like '%Benjamin Franklin Quotes%'
```

Comment: This does not perform full-text search and will be less efficient, especially on larger data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CONTAINS` and `CONTAINSTABLE` to match words and phrases.

> It performs a SQL Server full-text search on `full-text indexed`
>   columns containing character-based data types.[Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql)

```
select * from quotestable where CONTAINSTABLE(<tablename>, <ColumnName> ,'Benjamin Franklin Quotes')
```

`CONTAINS`

```
select * from quotestable where CONTAINS(<ColumnName> ,'"Benjamin Franklin Quotes"')
```

### word

Is a string of characters without spaces or punctuation.

### phrase

Is one or more words with spaces between each word.

> Phrases should be enclosed in double quotation marks ("").